# Using Python to Sort Child nodes in ElementTree

Tags: python, xml

Using Python 3.6 I have the data shown below in an xml.etree.ElementTree, the xml output using minidom.toprettyxml is shown below.

Before outputting to XML file I want to sort the Observation nodes using the PT attribute as the key. Whilst maintaining them in their correct Setup node.

This is for human reading purposes so that "Observation"s to the same "PT" are next to each other for checking, and possibly editing manually.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Survey name="filename here">
<Setup Station="13000" InstrumentHeight="0.0">
<Observation PT="SBDSE852S" HA="336.4813486486353" VA="87.14710969026532" SD="168.8937" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T15:47:39.03"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW801S" HA="260.9403472908128" VA="88.11265463299148" SD="224.61925" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T15:49:05.02"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW802S" HA="249.90718352859065" VA="88.20019946435063" SD="221.16645" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T15:49:56.05"/>
<Observation PT="SBZZ108R" HA="213.70079790293013" VA="87.84023471948807" SD="129.7161" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T15:52:17.04"/>
<Observation PT="SBGC210R" HA="131.9100549303175" VA="86.83200793760854" SD="31.1457" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T15:56:24.08"/>
<Observation PT="SBGC201R" HA="135.24920297621932" VA="87.42093979205845" SD="35.22585" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T15:57:19.08"/>
<Observation PT="SBGC300R" HA="341.0439328237202" VA="94.9602466892515" SD="16.3769" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T15:58:31.03"/>
<Observation PT="SBGC300R" HA="341.04415608692466" VA="94.96029050152956" SD="16.37675" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T15:59:36.06"/>
<Observation PT="SBGC301R" HA="38.42640483483226" VA="62.94180376378161" SD="7.64965" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T16:00:30.00"/>
</Setup>
<Setup Station="13001" InstrumentHeight="0.0">
<Observation PT="SBMOSI105S" HA="219.1574438207224" VA="86.35383331578822" SD="114.80255" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T16:23:19.02"/>
<Observation PT="SBGC300R" HA="325.74302017491317" VA="92.11049818613618" SD="47.7476" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T16:24:41.09"/>
<Observation PT="SBGC211R" HA="28.812142606012266" VA="64.25698410412183" SD="3.09595" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T16:25:27.03"/>
<Observation PT="SBGC201R" HA="106.99533526950749" VA="69.72099653614151" SD="3.5871" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T16:26:33.00"/>
<Observation PT="SBGC205R" HA="218.37692405247293" VA="89.04822501002216" SD="54.39005" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T16:29:09.08"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW801S" HA="267.32946750582306" VA="88.34255274658865" SD="243.62085" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T16:31:52.06"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW802S" HA="314.721253630381" VA="88.54860755337845" SD="157.8072" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T16:33:57.08"/>
</Setup>
<Setup Station="13002" InstrumentHeight="0.0">
<Observation PT="SBDSE852S" HA="354.56003832181915" VA="86.26412763401385" SD="106.19915" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T16:50:14.05"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW802S" HA="230.23156694768846" VA="88.40135183495619" SD="195.66635" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T16:51:15.06"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW803S" HA="226.3231844045" VA="88.39109127019015" SD="190.51305" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T16:52:16.01"/>
<Observation PT="SBMOSI106S" HA="187.5030019464116" VA="87.90409405603675" SD="157.9494" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T16:53:21.09"/>
<Observation PT="SBMOSI105S" HA="177.7109399309417" VA="87.82634136047567" SD="162.26865" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T16:53:46.03"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW901L" HA="18.641385181822482" VA="88.81520162210843" SD="279.27325" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T16:54:34.05"/>
<Observation PT="SBCS102R" HA="30.472020884007478" VA="88.96897044168112" SD="229.89725" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T16:56:05.08"/>
<Observation PT="SBMAR101R" HA="115.15110363661125" VA="90.62341735945346" SD="111.59105" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T16:57:01.04"/>
<Observation PT="SBWS503R" HA="170.9342211846535" VA="88.35831296215247" SD="164.259" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T16:58:10.06"/>
<Observation PT="SBWS501" HA="170.94714304485467" VA="89.04669321908078" SD="164.0959" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T16:58:59.03"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW301" HA="247.14604037600958" VA="87.51229331444699" SD="90.3724" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T17:00:30.09"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW301" HA="247.14649473022342" VA="87.51186961100264" SD="90.37245" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T17:00:48.06"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW400R" HA="285.3028326362871" VA="86.38080898316367" SD="49.01575" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T17:03:07.01"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW401R" HA="290.8527087321224" VA="86.70593184736977" SD="47.866" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T17:03:59.00"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW402R" HA="294.2822760524366" VA="86.25402786881274" SD="47.4713" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T17:05:53.03"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW403R" HA="298.85861455642316" VA="86.05166064933604" SD="47.2702" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T17:06:38.08"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW404R" HA="304.5271278231994" VA="86.5688961106161" SD="47.42415" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T17:07:39.05"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW406R" HA="318.67206741643145" VA="86.75902245348605" SD="50.45355" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T17:09:11.09"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW399R" HA="281.128645158443" VA="86.82591448775327" SD="50.2397" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-21T17:10:24.03"/>
</Setup>
<Setup Station="temp" InstrumentHeight="1.884">
<Observation PT="PSAL2" HA="24.068185256074244" VA="90.31240301123276" SD="320.11305" TH="1.621" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T13:28:56.09"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW202N" HA="245.06715785883776" VA="91.30625622434441" SD="123.5903" TH="1.656" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T13:30:15.08"/>
<Observation PT="r500" HA="123.62013964872175" VA="87.95780370215967" SD="107.6492" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T13:36:19.00"/>
<Observation PT="r500" HA="123.6203153322358" VA="87.95560522722639" SD="107.6492" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T13:36:27.09"/>
<Observation PT="r501" HA="130.84384878983974" VA="87.60171192430147" SD="82.6911" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T13:37:21.03"/>
<Observation PT="r501" HA="130.84344197077056" VA="87.60288510425652" SD="82.6914" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T13:37:30.06"/>
<Observation PT="r502" HA="241.99108056014126" VA="87.19343867580737" SD="61.9447" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T13:38:21.01"/>
<Observation PT="r502" HA="241.98884425774403" VA="87.19455666305743" SD="61.9449" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T13:38:31.09"/>
<Observation PT="r600" HA="68.57120263560662" VA="92.3163684670261" SD="118.4461" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T13:56:07.02"/>
<Observation PT="r500" HA="123.61993021166316" VA="87.9573717396231" SD="107.6494" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T14:04:03.04"/>
<Observation PT="r501" HA="130.84345337552227" VA="87.60319149277143" SD="82.6914" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T14:04:08.05"/>
<Observation PT="r502" HA="241.9909586725194" VA="87.19352688879648" SD="61.9443" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T14:04:15.05"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW302" HA="0.9611840906508888" VA="88.97526186816492" SD="68.7253" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T14:04:41.04"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW304" HA="11.876418609524151" VA="88.9228703279833" SD="93.1502" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T14:04:46.06"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW305" HA="14.585281351673927" VA="89.00020199601738" SD="103.8175" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T14:04:50.07"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW306" HA="16.628979034318128" VA="89.07322439029339" SD="115.2822" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T14:04:55.05"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW307" HA="18.016836604589763" VA="89.12660432855284" SD="126.4392" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T14:05:00.03"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW308" HA="18.97646817191739" VA="89.1495839098842" SD="137.5861" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T14:05:04.09"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW801" HA="282.4367435665059" VA="87.52781194884842" SD="83.3535" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T14:05:12.03"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW802" HA="251.37561061253402" VA="87.46269907513076" SD="71.0131" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T14:05:18.04"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW901L" HA="24.06832955528608" VA="90.31347245253119" SD="320.1218" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T14:05:40.08"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW901L" HA="24.06862223664632" VA="90.3122056771158" SD="320.1222" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T14:06:16.02"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW802" HA="251.37472085862015" VA="87.4610177726289" SD="71.013" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T14:06:24.05"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW801" HA="282.4352358258901" VA="87.52527499427424" SD="83.3537" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T14:06:30.01"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW308" HA="18.975997216986002" VA="89.14645385139994" SD="137.5857" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T14:06:37.09"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW307" HA="18.01649022896055" VA="89.12372242850097" SD="126.439" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T14:06:42.02"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW306" HA="16.62829528228866" VA="89.06971709469389" SD="115.2822" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T14:06:46.05"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW305" HA="14.58388062186225" VA="88.99686144292622" SD="103.8173" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T14:06:51.00"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW304" HA="11.876229549713685" VA="88.92077538288771" SD="93.1499" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T14:06:55.04"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW302" HA="0.9603442237767297" VA="88.97309321914179" SD="68.7252" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T14:07:00.02"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW301" HA="359.92363229042274" VA="88.63199758491982" SD="67.4118" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T14:07:04.09"/>
<Observation PT="r502" HA="241.99018294490645" VA="87.19196252085936" SD="61.9441" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T14:07:26.05"/>
<Observation PT="r501" HA="130.84347383084798" VA="87.60109905138432" SD="82.6912" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T14:07:34.07"/>
<Observation PT="r500" HA="123.61992158727509" VA="87.95497065120895" SD="107.6493" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T14:07:39.09"/>
<Observation PT="r500" HA="123.62028513159477" VA="87.9572041239818" SD="107.6494" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T14:07:49.08"/>
<Observation PT="r501" HA="130.84367916566217" VA="87.60325620929217" SD="82.6912" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T14:07:54.06"/>
<Observation PT="r502" HA="241.9912233760674" VA="87.1935815782532" SD="61.9441" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T14:08:02.07"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW301" HA="0.9584977661780416" VA="88.96683207497885" SD="68.7468" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T14:08:26.01"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW302" HA="0.958732819126125" VA="88.96676159695137" SD="68.7257" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T14:08:34.06"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW304" HA="11.876530899220256" VA="88.92270134487522" SD="93.1501" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T14:08:39.05"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW305" HA="14.584397100867974" VA="88.99938939303587" SD="103.8174" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T14:08:44.01"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW306" HA="16.628806129431375" VA="89.07242864357994" SD="115.2824" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T14:08:48.05"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW307" HA="18.017194777740073" VA="89.12641910538291" SD="126.4391" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T14:08:52.07"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW308" HA="18.975846749791895" VA="89.14930339919859" SD="137.5856" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T14:08:56.06"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW801" HA="282.43714353985325" VA="87.52692851263892" SD="83.3535" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T14:09:04.07"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW802" HA="251.37634286131873" VA="87.46239249096331" SD="71.0134" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T14:09:10.08"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW901L" HA="24.06769842498717" VA="90.3134788970486" SD="320.1223" TH="0.0" Face="F1" Time="2016-05-17T14:09:24.08"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW901L" HA="24.067475499507026" VA="90.31237002761458" SD="320.122" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T14:09:56.03"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW802" HA="251.37439019200136" VA="87.46064435777237" SD="71.0131" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T14:10:05.04"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW801" HA="282.4351764980064" VA="87.52506030786941" SD="83.3538" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T14:10:11.04"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW308" HA="18.975624352655785" VA="89.14663277740232" SD="137.5858" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T14:10:19.01"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW307" HA="18.016732660526543" VA="89.12383098706346" SD="126.4389" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T14:10:23.04"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW306" HA="16.6282233192303" VA="89.070045697122" SD="115.2823" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T14:10:27.07"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW305" HA="14.58426043757268" VA="88.99693515968664" SD="103.8174" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T14:10:32.03"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW304" HA="11.875751307745219" VA="88.92000621804061" SD="93.1501" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T14:10:36.09"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW302" HA="0.9602230204149578" VA="88.97245731897425" SD="68.7253" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T14:10:41.07"/>
<Observation PT="SBTW301" HA="359.9232477160593" VA="88.63150254883033" SD="67.4118" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T14:10:47.08"/>
<Observation PT="r502" HA="241.9898596249429" VA="87.19233103560146" SD="61.9442" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T14:11:07.04"/>
<Observation PT="r501" HA="130.8435622742349" VA="87.60103555448956" SD="82.691" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T14:11:14.08"/>
<Observation PT="r500" HA="123.61956410801093" VA="87.95483969210812" SD="107.6492" TH="0.0" Face="F2" Time="2016-05-17T14:11:20.01"/>
</Setup>
</Survey>
```

My complete Python code below, I can't get the Output to sort.

```
import untangle
import math

from xml.etree import ElementTree #modified ElementTree.py removing attribute sorting
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring
from xml.dom import minidom #modified minidom.py removing attribute sorting

def prettify(elem):
    """Return a pretty-printed XML string for the Element.
    """
    rough_string = ElementTree.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="")


## Start of Functions

def DMStoDD(DMSAng):
    DMSAng=str(DMSAng)
    p=DMSAng.find('.')
    D=DMSAng[0:p]
    M=DMSAng[p+1:p+3]
    S=DMSAng[p+3:p+5]
    SS='0.'+DMSAng[p+5:]
    DDAngStr=' '.join([D,' ',M,' ',S,' ',SS])
    DDAng= (
    float(D)
    +  float(M)/60
    +  float(S)/3600
    +  float(SS)/3600    
    )
    return DDAng



def DDtoDMS(DDAng2,Splaces=2):
    DDAng=float(DDAng2)
    D=int(DDAng)
    M=int((DDAng-D)*60)
    S=int((DDAng-D-M/60)*3600)
    SS=str(float((DDAng-D)-M/60-S/3600)*3600)[2:(2+Splaces)]

    DDtoDMS=(
        "%3.0f"%D + '.' +
        "%02.0f"%M +
        "%02.0f"%S +
        SS
        )

    return DDtoDMS

def DDtoDMSdash(DDAng2,Splaces=2):
    Splaces2 = Splaces
    if Splaces == 0:
        Splaces2 = -1
    DDAng=float(DDAng2)
    D=int(DDAng)
    M=int((DDAng-D)*60)
    S=float((DDAng-D-M/60)*3600)

    DDtoDMSdash=(
        "%3.0f"%D + '-' +
        "%02.0f"%M + '-' +
        ("%0"+str((Splaces2)+3)+"."+str(Splaces)+"f")%S
        )

    return DDtoDMSdash


##start of code
tree = untangle.parse('XML1.xml')
surv = tree.LandXML.Survey

## write ElementTree ROOT
Out = Element('Survey')
Out.set('name','filename here')

for OG in surv.ObservationGroup:
    ST=OG.TargetPoint['name']
    OGID=OG['id']
    ##find corresponding Instrument Height by cross-referencing to InstrumentSetup
    ISID=OGID[1:]    
    IH=0.000
    for IS in surv.InstrumentSetup:
        if IS['id'] == ISID:
            IH=float(IS['instrumentHeight'])

    ## Write ElementTree
    Set=SubElement(Out,'Setup')
    Set.set('Station',str(ST))
    Set.set('InstrumentHeight',str(IH))



    for RO in OG.RawObservation:
        HA=DMStoDD(str(RO['horizAngle']))
        VA=DMStoDD(str(RO['zenithAngle']))
        SD=float(RO['slopeDistance'])
        TH=float(RO['targetHeight'])
        if RO['directFace'] == 'true':
            F='F1'
        else:
            F='F2'
        PT=str(RO.TargetPoint['name'])
        T=str(RO['timeStamp'])
        ## Convert face 2 observations to face 1
        if F=='F2':
            HA=HA-180
            if HA < 0:
                HA = HA+360
            VA=360-VA
        ## Calc Vertical distance inclu0ding IH and TH
        ##VD=IH+SD*math.cos(math.radians(VA))-TH

        ##Write ElementTree
        Obs=SubElement(Set,'Observation',
                               {'PT':str(PT),
                                'HA':str(HA),
                                'VA':str(VA),
                                'SD':str(SD),
                                'TH':str(TH),
                                'Face':str(F),
                                'Time':str(T)
                                }
                               )

container = Out.find("Setup")

for a in container:
    data = []
    for elem in a:
        key = elem.findtext("PT")
        data.append((key,elem))
    data.sort()
    a[:] = [item[-1] for item in data]


print (prettify(Out))
#print (ElementTree.tostring(Out))







##        print (
##            ST,' ',
##            PT,' ',
##            "{:.4f}".format(HA),' ',
##            "{:.4f}".format(VA),' ',
##            "{:.3f}".format(SD),' ',
##            "{:.3f}".format(VD),' ',
##            "{:.3f}".format(IH),' ',
##            "{:.3f}".format(TH),' ',
##            F,' ',
##            T
##            )
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or a code writing service.  Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains. [The Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) and [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) may be worthwhile reads.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
def sortchildrenby(parent, attr):
    parent[:] = sorted(parent, key=lambda child: child.get(attr))

tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
parent = tree.find("Setup")
sortchildrenby(parent, "PT")
tree.write("new_data.xml")
```

Comment: Sorry that doesn't seem to work. I wish I understood it better, maybe it'ss something simple.

Comment: @user19109 didnt it sort the "PT" tag as you wish ?

Comment: no the output was exactly the same as I originally posted above

Comment: @user19109 can you try again

Comment: no I tried that snippet as well, the original order is still preserved. No sorting appears to have taken place.

Comment: I'll study and try to exactly understand the code you suggested and maybe I will work it out.

Comment: @user19109 i tried this code on my computer and it sorted the xml file by "PT" tag
1)parse the tree
2)take the setup tag from tree
3)sort the Setup tags childs by "PT" Tag
4)write it to the new file

Comment: Maybe it's because I am working on an ElementTree  with the name of "Out", not an XML file? I'll have another look tomorrow. Thanks